# mysql conditional insert on duplicate update - multiple records

Tags: sql, mysql, insert

How can I use the `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` with a multiple value INSERT?

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name 
  (key_id,field1,filed2) 
VALUES
  (1,2,3),
  (1,5,6),
  (1,8,9);
```

Comment: What is your intended outcome?  I can only get MySQL to allow `(1,5,6) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE key_id=key_id+1`, but on execution I only have one row in the table, values: `2, 2, 3`.

Comment: well the SQL is an example but the expected outcome would be to run one query that would insert if new, update if duplicate for multiple values. so if key_id 1, 3, and 5 are already in the DB and I run INSERT for 2, 3, 4 and 6. 2,4 and 6 should insert and 3 should update since it was a duplicate

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can not try it right now, but can't you use this syntax

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=VALUES(a)+VALUES(b);
```

from the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)?

Guess your syntax would then look like this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name
  (key_id,field1,filed2) 
VALUES
  (1,2,3),
  (1,5,6),
  (1,8,9)
ON DUPLICATE KEY
  UPDATE field1=VALUES(field1), field2=VALUES(field2);
```

Comment: I must have missed this, thnx